# Category ordering not working

Tags: magento-2.1, category

I am trying to arrange the category listing order in the top navigation on the storefront but every time I drag and drop the category at the required location it doesn't work.

After page refresh, category came back to the previous location. 
Example : 
Previous order : 
category 1 
category 2 
category 3

Required order: 
category 1 
category 3 
category 2

After page refresh it came back to the previous order as follows :
category 1 
category 2 
category 3

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: check the js console. maybe there is an error on the category move ajax call

Comment: No, there is no error message. There is only success message "You moved the category".